# Set new application replica for each request

Tags: python, kubernetes, service, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm trying to deploy my application on a K8S cluster and expose it with a service. My application receives several video streams and needs to handle each stream with a different replica. Is there a way to scale the application with a new replica for each incoming request?
I've found horizontal pod autoscaler but don't know how to configure a metric like this

Anyone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more information - which metrics you plan to use for HPA? According to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) usually it is an average CPU utilization, average memory utilization, or any other custom metric.

Comment: I would configure a custom metric to force K8S to allocate a new replica of my application for each ingress request. In my case each request is a video stream and I need to make K8S to forward each new stream to a new replica of the application. Is it possible? Or can I usa e different architecture to achieve this goal?

Comment: You can look at this solution from [Knative](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/autoscaling/rps-target/#configuring-the-requests-per-second-rps-target)